# Unable to import class within package

Tags: python, python-import

i have following project structure: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYFiu.png)

and here is content of files:

```python
# run.py
from module.submodule.base import DefaultObject

d = DefaultObject()


# module/sumbodule/base.py
from module.submodule.modulea import A

class BaseObject(object):
    pass

class DefaultObject(BaseObject):

    def return_something(self):
        return A()


# module/submodule/modulea.py
from module.submodule.moduleb import B

class A(object):

    def return_something(self):
        return B()


# module/submodule/moduleb.py
from module.submodule.base import BaseObject

class B(BaseObject):
    pass
```

and when I try to run `python3 run.py` I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseObject`

I don't understand why I am able to import `class B` in `modulea.py`, but I am not able to `class BaseObject` in `moduleb.py`

What is correct way to make imports in such situation?

Comment: Why are you importing from `module.submodule` instead of just `module`?

Comment: Corrected. Because they are under `submodule` directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a circular import - base imports modulea which imports moduleb which imports base. Python doesn't support circular imports so it cannot technically work, and even for languages that technically supports them, circular dependencies are a very bad thing anyway.

Your solutions here are either to regroup interdependant objects (classes, functions etc) in a same module - note that Python is not Java and doesn't require "one module per class" (it's even actually an antipattern in Python) - or to move `DefaultObject` to it's own module.